# Build and install OpenCV with python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I cloned `opencv` and `opencv-contrib` GitHub and build and install with `cuda`. Following are the python flags used.

[image: opencv python flags]

In the opencv build, I can see `cv2` module and python samples.

`s1n7ax@s1n7ax:~/workspace/opencv/build$ tree python_loader samples`

```
python_loader
├── cv2
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── _extra_py_code
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── load_config_py2.py
│   └── load_config_py3.py
└── setup.py
samples
...
├── python
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   │   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   │   └── progress.marks
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   ├── CTestTestfile.cmake
│   └── Makefile
...
```

When installing, it logs following message.

`sudo make install`

```
-- OpenCV Python: during development append to PYTHONPATH: /home/s1n7ax/workspace/opencv/build/python_loader
```

After the installation is completed, I added the path to and ran python.

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/s1n7ax/workspace/opencv/build/python_loader && python3
```

However, I'm not able to import the `cv2` module correctly.

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, May 27 2021, 13:30:53) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/s1n7ax/workspace/opencv/build/python_loader/cv2/__init__.py", line 117, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/home/s1n7ax/workspace/opencv/build/python_loader/cv2/__init__.py", line 73, in bootstrap
    load_first_config([
  File "/home/s1n7ax/workspace/opencv/build/python_loader/cv2/__init__.py", line 70, in load_first_config
    raise ImportError('OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: {}. Check OpenCV installation.'.format(fnames))
ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config-3.8.py', 'config-3.py']. Check OpenCV installation.
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: You could try ``` pip3 install --upgrade opencv-python```  and ``pip3 install --upgrade pyinstaller`` and in cmake, check your python3 Paths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After few tries, I realized following flags needs to be filled.

```
PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3
PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.8
PYTHON3_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so
PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packades/numpy/core/include
PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packades
```

To find these paths, I used `find` command.

I created a [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/whAFl-izD-4) so that I won't forget these later on

Comment: So, are you saying that while building OpenCV, we should have ALL parameters configured before building? Or, after OpenCV is successfully built and installed, should ALL the parameters configured afterwards ???